# Is wearing ring a sunnah for men?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, men

Is wearing ring a Sunnah of the Prophet (PBUH) for men?

**If yes:**

> What are the etiquettes in that(ie,which type of ring, in which hand,
>   in which finger...)?

**If NO:**

> Why many of the muslim scholars and brothers are wearing ring?

Please, provide some references from hadiths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **NOTE:**

Some scholars say that *Wearing any ring is not Sunnah since the Prophet Mohammed (PBUH) used to wear a ring for signing letters sent to other kings. Because they told him that kings would not accept any letter that has not been signed. Hence, Scholars say it is Sunnah for those who use it to sign papers and documents. And some say it is Sunnah even for normal people

- **Hanafi:** For Rulers, it is Sunnah.
- **Maliki:** It is permissible and recommended to wear a ring since you want to imitate the Prophet (PBUH). and Haram if you wear a ring to show off
- **Hanbli:** It is permissible and **NOT recommended**
- **Shafi:** Sunnah for Rulers and Normal Muslims

---

The Prophet used to wear a ring but scholars have differed about which finger should the person put his ring on because there are many authentic hadiths that tells us that the prophet used to wear it in different fingers and different hands.

**1- Left hand - Maliki, Hanafi, and Hanbali**

**2- Right hand - Shafi**

But Ibn al Qayim said: "There are different hadiths about wearing the ring in the right or left hand but all of them are authentic(correct)".

And Sheikh Ibn Uthaymeen said: "It is considered a Sunnah if you wear the ring in the right hand or the left hand"

Now this is a Hadith that answers all of your questions:

> Thabit narrated that : They asked Anas about the ring of the Messenger of Allah [SAW] and he said: "It is as if I can see the shining of his silver ring, and he raised his right little finger."

An-Nasai (Sahih)

---

More Hadiths:

> Anas reported that the ring of Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) was on this, and he pointed toward the little finger of his left hand.

Sahih Muslim

> Nafi' said that Ibn 'Umar used to wear his signet-ring on his left hand.

Abi Dawud

> Yahya related to me from Malik that Sadaqa ibn Yasar said, "I asked Said ibn al-Musayyab about wearing a ring. He said, 'Wear it, and tell people that I gave you that decision.' "

Muwata Malik

**The ring was made from:**

> Anas b. Malik reported that the ring of Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) was made of silver and it had an Abyssinian stone in it.

Sahih Muslim

> Narrated Anas:
>   The ring of the Prophet was of silver, and its stone was of silver too.

Bukhary

> Narrated Anas: The signet-ring of the Prophet (saws) was all of silver as was also its stone.

Sunan Abi-Dawud

**it is permissible to wear a ring of iron**

> In al-Saheehayn it is narrated from Sahl ibn Sa’d al-Ansaari (RA) that the Prophet (PBUH) said to the one who proposed marriage to the woman who had offered herself in marriage to the Prophet (PBUH):
>   "Look for something (to give as a dowry), even if it is a ring of iron."

[Abu Dawood] and [al-Nasaa’i]

Thus it is clear that the more correct view is that it is not makrooh (discourage) to wear a ring of iron. But wearing a ring of silver is better, because the ring of the Prophet (PBUH) was made of silver, as is proven in al-Saheehayn.

---

However, you are **not allowed to wear a golden ring:**

> Abu Huraira reported that Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) forbade the wearing of gold signet ring.

Sahih Muslim

> It was narrated from 'Abidah, from 'Ali, he said: "He forbade red Al-Mayathir, wearing Al-Qassi, and gold rings."

An-Nasai (Sahih)

> It was narrated that Ibn 'Umar said: "The Messenger of Allah [SAW] started to wear a gold ring, and the people started to wear gold rings. The Messenger of Allah [SAW] said: 'I was wearing this ring, but I will never wear it again.' He threw it away and the people threw their rings away.'"

An-Nasai(Sahih)

Another thing, the prophet **used to remove his ring** when entering the bathroom because it was written on it (There is not God but allah, Mohammed is the messenger of Allah)

> Narrated Anas bin Malik (rad): Allah’s Messenger (saw) used to remove his ring when entering the lavatory.[Reported by Al-Arba’a and it is defective].

Buligh Al-Maram

**Another prohibition** is that you must not wear it in these 2 fingers

> 'Ali reported: Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) forbade me that I should wear a ring in this and that finger of mine, and he pointed to the middle finger and the next one.

Sahih Muslim

Comment: Dear mate, As far as i know, it has mentioned in the narrations that wearing ring is a Sunnah. so you can read my answer as the following answer.

Answer (score 2):

**According to the viewpoint of the Prophet (pbuh) and Shia (narrations), it is a tradition to wear a ring.** The design, material and appearance of the ring have all been mentioned in the hadiths. On the other hand, It has also been pointed out to wear the ring on the right hand. Of course it is not a Wajib (indispensable) act, it is just a Mustahab act.

**For instance, our hadiths have mentioned regarding Aghigh:**

> aghigh (a type of stone, mostly found in Yemen, normally dark red or
>   brown) has been recommended and it has been said to bring abundance
>   and protection from disaster and catastrophe.[1]

For further information and to find your complete answer ( regarding the types of rings, stones, and likewise which hand and finger..), I strongly recommend you to see the following links.

Wasa’el-ul-Shia, v.5, pg.91.

Source(s):

http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1144

http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1962

Comment: Who wrote this.... "aghigh (a type of stone, mostly found in Yemen, normally dark red or brown) has been recommended and it has been said to bring abundance and protection from disaster and catastrophe" its a total shirk when we believe ring would bring abundance and protection. Allah is only one to give those thing. every thing is from Him not from tiny ring... be carefull when you post such thing. you have to answer these in qayamah..